# Is there a list of Android widgets present on Google Glass XE11?

Tags: google-glass

As seen by the GDK sample code, there is a set of Android Widget classes (TextView, etc) that are supported on Google Glass. Has anyone compiled a list? I would love to know what options I am working with prior to the official GDK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to what I have gathered, you should be able to use **any** UI element within your application using GDK (it's simply an Android activity displayed in Glass). There are some services that aren't available though, that is really the only limitation at the moment. Some limitations I've spotted are: SpeechRecognizer not available - use RecognizerIntent instead, GPS might have some issues/limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Since Glass is built on Android, all of the standard Android widgets are available. You should, however, restrict yourself to widgets that provide a high-quality user experience on Glass. For example, buttons and checkboxes aren't very usable since the user can't click on them directly.